# Why does water warm gradually when a faucet is opened?

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life, water

When you turn on a hot water tap after some idle period, you first get the cooler water that's been in the pipe, then gradually it warms up to the tank temperature.

I've wondered why the warmup is gradual. I picture a 'front' of hot water pushing the cooler water along until it arrives at the tap, but clearly that's not what happens. Why not?

Comment: The pipe has to warm up as well, cooling the hot water flowing through it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, the water stays in the pipe for hours before you open the tap. This would make the water stored in the pipe pretty cool.

Now when you turn on the heater, all the water stored inside the heater is being heated and the hot water is only inside the heater.

Now when you open the pipe, the cool water that is initially in the pipe first comes out which is pretty cool. however this water is finite and after all this water flows out, the hot water flows through the cold pipe which reduces the temperature of the water.

Soon enough, the hot water flowing through the pipe sufficiently heats up the cold pipe which then gradually increases the temperature of water coming out of the pipe.

[image]

Comment: I did neglect to consider the state of the pipe itself, which matters if the pipe is conductive. To nail this down we'd have to test with plastic pipe (-:

Comment: @JimMack:  Even a plastic pipe will absorb *some* heat from the water moving through it.  The difference in thermal conductivity & heat capacity would probably make the temperature profile at the tap different, though.

Answer (score 2):

What do you think the temperature profile looks along the pipe in the steady state after a few hours of no warm water having moved through the system? Surely water temperature would fall as you move away from the heater if the water in the heater is kept at a constant temperature by a thermostat. Then all that water moved through the pipe, so you get cold water first, then increasingly warm water until you actually get water that left the heater not long ago.

The pipe having to warm up, thus cooling water flowing through it, as Jon Custer pointed out in the comments has an effect too.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the bit about a temperature gradient in the water standing in the pipe, but I do see how the effect of warming the pipe could account for this